# How to avoid base template from being cached in django 1.3

Tags: django

I've been updating recently to django 1.3 and got the following issue:

I have a base template 'base.html' which depends on the state (saved in request.session) of the user session, and therefore should be rendered every time a page is loaded/reloaded. All my pages are extended from this base template according to common use:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

This has not been an issue before, but now I noticed that the base template gets somehow cached (i.e. it is not getting reloaded on every request). I'm using the following template loaders:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Can somebody please advice me on how to disable this caching??? Let me know if you need some further information - thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Pages are rendered from within views.py as follows:

```
render_to_response('page.html', RequestContext(request,{}))
```

Comment: "Somehow getting cached"? How do you know? What are the results that lead you to suspect this? How are you rendering the template?

Comment: After a change in base.html, this change is directly visible on a previously not visited page, while a previously visited page does not display the change before a couple of minutes have gone. This makes me suspect some sort of caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was client side caching. The problem is solved site wide with the following middleware:

```
from django.utils.cache import add_never_cache_headers

class DisableClientSideCachingMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        add_never_cache_headers(response)
        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late but I ran into the same problem recently, and I found another (possibly simpler) solution:

In Django's cache framework, you can use a decorator called @cache_control to take care of the header you are sending, for example:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control
@cache_control(must_revalidate=True)
def my_view(request):
...
```

will tell the caches to revalidate every time the view is accessed.